# How to snag highest numbered XML item with PHP?

Tags: php, xml

I've basically got an XML file full of product information for use in an ecommerce system. I've been creating a script that converts these XML files into a .CSV with the data structured in a format the ecommerce system can handle (So I don't need to copy/paste columns over every time the vendor provides new XML files). The category of each product is defined like this:

```
<web_category1>3</web_category1>
<web_category2>1</web_category2>
<web_category3>6</web_category3>
```

web_category3 being the category of the item and 1 and 2 being the parent categories of the product's category. The thing is that some items are nested under 2 categories..or sometimes 5. So I need to figure out a way for PHP to grab the web_category with the highest number after it since that's always going to be the product's category.

Thanks!

Comment: Are they always numerically sorted like this? So 1, 2 then 3. Or can they also be 1, 3 and then 2?

Comment: It's always 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc. Just need to grab w/e the value of the highest numbered web_category is.

Comment: **Congratulations on your first post**; welcome to stack overflow, Jeremy.

Comment: Thanks! It's a credit to the site that I've been using it for years and only now have had to ask a question because I couldn't find the answer elsewhere :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ben's answer is correct, but is a little intense for me. `SimpleXMLElement` objects are nice because you can easily cast them to an array. So, a simpler solution would be to cast it to an array and use `max` to determine the highest value in the resulting array:

```
$str = '
<item>
    <web_category1>3</web_category1>
    <web_category2>1</web_category2>
    <web_category3>6</web_category3>
</item>
';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($str);
echo max((array)$xml); // outputs: 6
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment below, let's assume you need to get the max of *all* the `<item>` elements that occur in an XML file and not just one (like above). To handle this you could use [`SimpleXMLElement::xpath`<sup>*docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) to get an array of all the occurrences of `<item>` then execute the same casting trick inside a loop over the xpath result:

```
$str = '
<xml>
  <product1>
    <item>
      <web_category1>3</web_category1>
      <web_category2>1</web_category2>
      <web_category3>6</web_category3>
    </item>
  </product1>
  <product2>
    <item>
      <web_category4>17</web_category4>
      <web_category5>0</web_category5>
    </item>
  </product2>
</xml>
';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($str);

$allItems = array();
$items = $xml->xpath('//item');
foreach($items as $item) {
  $allItems = array_merge($allItems, (array)$item);
}
echo max($allItems); // outputs: 17
```

**UPDATE 2**

Okay, last time. If this isn't exactly what you're trying to do, you should at least have enough examples to figure it out from here. Consider:

```
$str = '
<xml>
  <product1>
    <web_category1>3</web_category1>
    <web_category2>1</web_category2>
    <web_category3>6</web_category3>
  </product1>
  <product2>
    <web_category4>17</web_category4>
    <web_category5>0</web_category5>
  </product2>
  <product3>
    <web_category6>17</web_category6>
    <web_category7>21</web_category7>
  </product3>
</xml>
';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($str);

// assumes that product node names start with "product"
$products = $xml->xpath("//*[starts-with(name(),'product')]");
foreach ($products as $p) {
  $catNames = array_keys((array)$p);
  $catNums  = preg_replace("/[^\d]/", "", $catNames);
  echo $p->getName() . ' - highest category: ' . max($catNums) . "\n";
}
```

The above code outputs the following:

```
product1 - highest category: 3
product2 - highest category: 5
product3 - highest category: 7
```

Comment: I like this because it's a great deal more simple, but the issue I would run into (and keep in mind that my terminology for XML is WAY off) is that each section (each product) has a few web_category items in it. Ranging between 1 web_category to like 4 or so. How would I go about making it so my script pulled out all of the existing web_category items per product and run them through the max() function?

Comment: I think I worded it wrong. sorry sorry. I have a while() in which each product is written to a different line in a .CSV. So I need it to sniff out the highest #'d web_category per item and output it into that product's line in the csv.


so if product A has:

web_category1

web_category2

web_category3


and B has:

web_category1

web_category2


I need it to snag web_cat3 from A and web_cat2 from B. I hope this is makign some sense...it makes sense in my head at least lol

Comment: @JeremyDuenas So do you want the highest value from inside any occurring `<web_category9>` or just want to know that `9` **is the highest** occurring "web_category" node? Further, will the number `9` *always* be the last character in the node name? Because it affects my answer.

Comment: I need to know what the highest occuring "web_category" node is per product in my while() statement. so I supposed I need to know that 9 is the highest occuring web_category node. No, 9 won't always be the last character in the node.

Comment: oh man I think I'm just making it more confusing. Disregard everything butm y first sentence in the last comment. That first sentence pretty much explains it as clearly as I can think to put it. Also I meant that it's wrapped in a foreach(), not a while(), if that matters.

Comment: Not going to get a chance to plug it into my code before I head off from work today, but that looks like it should do what I need it to do. Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 0):

assuming your XML is something like this:

```
<item>
    <web_category1>3</web_category1>
    <web_category2>1</web_category2>
    <web_category3>6</web_category3>
</item>
```

And you have a SimpleXMLElement object for `<item>`, this should do it:

```
$highest_web_category_number = -1;
$value_of_highest_web_category_number = -1;
foreach($item->getChildren() as $name => $data) {
    if(strpos($name, 'web_category') === 0) {
        $web_category_number = substr($name, strlen('web_category'));
        if($web_category_number > $highest_web_category_number) {
            $highest_web_category_number = $web_category_number
            $value_of_highest_web_category_number = $data;
        }
    }
}
```